# want to get dynamic values into constant in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and simply want to get dynamic values into 'constant' object.

Is there a way to add my dynamic values into the constant? is there a better way then what i am doing.

**Is there an order thing in angular where constant has limitation and cannot call cannot get values to certain objects (services, rootScope,...).**

Thanks in advance

Here are the codes.

when i manually assign a `static` data (object,etc..) to the variable `CONFIG`

**This work**

```
kpApp.constant('CONFIG',{ name :'paul'  });
```

when i try to dynamically get a value from a `webservice`

**This not work**

```
kpApp.constant('CONFIG', (function (initService) {
     return initService.list();
}()));
```

**service that works**

```
var init = angular.module('app.main.initServices', []);
init.service('initService', function ($http) { 
 ...
$http.get('data/init.json').success(function (data) {
    inits = data;
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    inits = [{ "description": "error"}];
});

this.list = function () { 
    return inits;
}
 ...
```

Comment: Constant are suppose to be ... constant. If you wanna save different value dynamically, you should use a factory. This factory can be inject everywhere as much as constant.

Comment: @Pierre-AlexandreMoller the factory isn't injected anywhere. It's the service **returned** by the factory that is injected.

Comment: @JBNizet You understood what I mean .... And it's just a guideline. The purpose wasn't to explain how the factory work.

Comment: I understood, yes. Maybe because I do know how that works. But the OP does not. Why use the incorrect terminology instead of the correct one? Do you see any advantage?

Comment: i was just thinking of using a constant in order to save dynamic data once comming from a database so i can get my configuration data saved for my app to start. these values would never be changed after.

Comment: i injected initService :    kpApp.constant('CONFIG', (function (initService) {
     return initService.list();
}()));

Comment: not sure how things work in angularjs, can we assign a constant's value that came from a database?

Comment: I know that i can simply use the $rootScope as a global variable but read that it's not best practice